# Concatenate 1 to many strings from a table that start and end with a different pattern into a new field

Tags: sql-server, loops, concatenation, alteryx

I'm familiar with and have access to SQL Server Mgmt studio and Alteryx but haven't had a need to use loops. So I think I may have to use one for a string pattern I'm looking to concatenate into a new column. Can anyone help or suggest, if using a loop makes sense and how best to get started.

The link below has an example of data I'm looking to parse the "original text" field and have it look like the "new text" field that I manually did that I'm trying to automate. I think there will be more patterns as I go through this more but figured a start is better then nothing.

[Data with Original Text and New Text field I want to create after parsing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7nrf.png)

Below is the psuedocode I have done so far in what I'm thinking could work..

While End of file

CASE WHEN ORIGINAL TEXT STARTS WITH ANY OF THE FOLLOWING PATTERNS START CONCATENATING AND END ONCE ANY OF THE 5 PATTERNS START AGAIN AND CREATE NEW TEXT RECORD

(PATTERN 1: |###|

PATTERN 2    :##:

PATTERN 3    :##A:

PATTERN 4     #/

PATTERN 5   (#:

END AS NEW TEXT FIELD
Update 10-21- I got the code below working to search by colon as a first step..

```
if object_id('tempdb..#LETTERS') is not null

drop table #LETTERS
SELECT *
INTO #LETTERS
FROM [dbo].[tbl_TEXT_LETTERS]

declare @LINE_counter      int
declare @max_LINE_counter  int
set @LINE_counter = 0
select @max_LINE_counter = max(LINE) from #LETTERS

while @LINE_counter <= @max_LINE_counter

--

begin

    declare       @NEW_TEXT     varchar(200)


    select @NEW_TEXT =

    case when LETTERS.[TEXT] LIKE '%:%'

        THEN LETTERS.[TEXT]

        ELSE 'NOTHING'

    END

    FROM #LETTERS LETTERS
    where line = @LINE_counter

    --print @line_counter
    print @NEW_TEXT

    set @LINE_counter= @LINE_counter + 1

end
```

Comment: In Alteryx, for looping logic of this nature (toggling between looking for a 'start' vs. looking for an 'end'), I would use the R tool and write an actual loop that maintains the toggle. Alteryx iterative macros are a bit of overhead for that. I also recommend pasting your actual sample data into the question, rather than an image of it.

Comment: Hi John, I will give that a try. I'm unable to upload files. But below is the column I'm trying to parse.|001|12345
|002|2962236
|003|026803:20F:123
1/ABC
2/DEF
3/GRS
:20A:54321
:59:/1234567
1234 MAINST
New York, NY
12345 POST
:20:19990101
|201|04201908190002
|123|987955:05K:/123456
12 MAINST
New York, NY
12345 POST
(1:abcd)
(2:abcdefg)
(3:ajjklj))
(4:
:20:hjkhfakh
-)(2:(abc:123))

Comment: I've tried the following so far in SQL, will need to try R next in Alteryx. Right now just trying to do a basic loop to search for a colon.

Answer (score 0):

As you need so many different patterns, REGEX is going to be the easiest way. A REGEX tool set to Tokenise and split to rows with the following expression will get you a list of all the terms you need to split on. Note that :20F: didn't match a pattern that you listed and so I improvised

\|\d{3}\||:\d\d[A-Z]{0,1}:|\d/|(\d:

What this means is:
A pipe followed by 3 digits and a pipe - \|\d{3}\|
OR - |
A colon followed by 2 digits and 0 or 1 capital letters, then a colon - :\d\d[A-Z]{0,1}:
OR - |
A digit followed by a forward slash - \d/
OR - |
A bracket then a digit then a colon - (\d:

Once you have that list:
Find Replace: Replace all of those with a chevron (^)
Text to Columns: Split on the chevron to new rows. 
Sample tool: Skip 1 row
Join: By record position back to the list
Formula: Create new field with Concatenated data.

Note: I've tried to give the solution here as it's a long way from where you are. Often times on the Alteryx Community you would get a built out solution.

Comment: Thanks KaneG, I started putting the regex formula in Alteryx but I get an error for the last pattern below. The errors says there is a regex mismatch on "(" and ")" character 35. Also I may give the Alteryx community a try as well, thanks for the suggestion.                                                                                                       4)OR - |
A bracket then a digit then a colon - (\d:

Comment: As a work around I did the following replace statement and changed the 4th pattern from the regex formula. REPLACE(REPLACE([TEXT],"(",":"),"(",":")  New Regex formula:  \|\d{3}\||:\d\d[A-Z]{0,1}:|\d/|:\d[A-Z]{0,1}:

Comment: Hi Kane, I uploaded my workflow to the Alteryx community with your suggestions. I didn't add the sample workflow as it seemed to only be skipping the 1st row but I may have misunderstood the use. I also have some more patterns I'm implementing but I think if I can get a few working I should be able to figure out the rest on my own. For reference I added the following link. https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/Concatenate-1-to-many-strings-from-a-table-that-start-and-end/td-p/479961

Comment: I put your formula in and then your modified REGEX and it works for me. If you are doing that replace though, you can shorten your REGEX to 

\|\d{3}\||:\d+[A-Z]{0,1}:|\d/

Comment: Thanks regex workflow is working. I think the only part I still need assistance on is the concatenation part, do I need to do a loop or anything?